# How to use fireevent IE8?

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

IE6,7,8 this code dose not working

anybody help me.

how can i fix it??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call (event) {
  if (document.createEventObject) {   // IE before version 9
   var mouseclickEvent = document.createEventObject (window.event);
   mouseclickEvent.button = 1;  // left button is down
   document.getElementById("test4").fireEvent ("onclick", mousedownEvent);
  }
}
</script>
<body>
  <button id="test" onmouseover="call (event);">call</button>
  <input id="test3" type="file" onclick="alert(6)"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

There're several problems in you code:

1. `event` and `window.event` is redundant (and, I'm not sure though, may cause error);
2. There's no element with id `test4`.

The following code has been tested on IE8 and IE6:

```
<script>
function call()
{
    if(document.createEventObject)
    {
        var evt=document.createEventObject();
        evt.button=1;
        document.getElementById("test").fireEvent("onclick",evt);
    }
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="call();">Fire</button>
<input type="text" id="test" onclick="alert(6);" />
```